# Place single quotes around strings with sed

Tags: sed

I have a file that contains contents like this:

```
proxy.config.cluster.mc_group_addr  224.0.1.37
proxy.config.log.logging_enabled    3
proxy.config.log.squid_log_enabled  1
```

I need to modify it to

```
'proxy.config.cluster.mc_group_addr'  : '224.0.1.37'
'proxy.config.log.logging_enabled'    : '3'
'proxy.config.log.squid_log_enabled'  : '1'
```

I tried various sed commands like

```
sed 's/[A-Za-z]*[0-9]*[.]
```

But they did not work..

Answer (score 0):

got it working.

```
sed -r "s/^|$/'/g" records.config  | sed "s/\s/': '/g"
```

This looks to be good. hope this is better way.

Answer (score 0):

Using backreference:

```
sed 's/^\(.*\) \(.*\)/'\''\1'\'': '\''\2'\''/' file
```

or with surrounding double quotes:

```
sed "s/^\(.*\) \(.*\)/'\1': '\2'/" file
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
awk -v OFS=":" '{print v$1v,v$2v}' v="'" f
'proxy.config.cluster.mc_group_addr':'224.0.1.37'
'proxy.config.log.logging_enabled':'3'
'proxy.config.log.squid_log_enabled':'1'
```

Answer (score 0):

***sed*** solution:

```
sed -E "s/^([^ ]+) (.+)$/'\1': '\2'/" testfile
```

`^([^ ]+)` - will match a sequence of characters excepting space at the start of the line

The output:

```
'proxy.config.cluster.mc_group_addr': '224.0.1.37'

'proxy.config.log.logging_enabled': '3'

'proxy.config.log.squid_log_enabled': '1'
```

---

***awk*** solution(without empty lines):

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=" "; ORS="\n";}{ if(NF) print "\47"$1"\47: \47"$2"\47"}' testfile
```

`if(NF)` - checks if a line is not empty to perform the next expression
`"\47"` - points to a single quote `'`

The output:

```
'proxy.config.cluster.mc_group_addr': '224.0.1.37'
'proxy.config.log.logging_enabled': '3'
'proxy.config.log.squid_log_enabled': '1'
```